# Trendmicro clones authenticated requests - showing up in my error logs

Tags: error, logging, crawl-errors

I'm having various errors, from unauthenticated requests for using some AJAX requests (which need authentication).

While I have clients from Belgium, the IP addresses match a IP in the form of `150.70.*.*`, all are using Windows XP and IE 6 or IE 8.

When I do a lookup, I receive this: http://ip-lookup.net/index.php Which means that it originates from Japan and it's a static IP from trendsmicro.com, a security suite.

Any idea if I can blacklist this? I'd like to keep my errors close to zero. But this is one I can't solve without blacklisting the IP range.

What should I do and what does trendsmicro try to do when cloning the request?

Comment: The IP lookup link you included gives me information about my current IP address.  I don't think that can be the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out about this: [TrendMicro is recording every click](http://compxnonsense.blogspot.be/2011/04/trendmicro-is-recording-your-every.html)

Seems to be TrendMicro's form of spyware... (*protection*kuch*) and i'm going to block the IP-Range. I won't condolence bad behaviour